# How to know the exit code of a process run in the background

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that runs a process in the background while shows a progress bar until the mentioned process ends. my question is, how can I check the exit code of that process??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $? variable:

```
command & #run command in background
pid=$!    #get pid
wait $!   #wait for the sucker to finish
status=$? #exitcode for pid
```

Comment: I updated my response.. use 'wait'

Comment: but is this true if I'm using sleep instead and a bunch of echo's while the process runs in the background?

Answer (score 4):

The [`wait`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins) builtin will return the exit code of the waited process if you specify a PID or job spec. (Note that it returns zero if you don't specify either of those.)

Here's how you could use it:

```
#! /bin/bash

(exit 10)&
pid=$!
wait $pid
echo $?
```

This will print `10`.

Comment: but is this true if I'm using sleep instead and a bunch of echo's while the process runs in the background?